# UWP c# Dynamically change chart when changing data

Tags: c#, charts, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm trying to make a chart (UWP-c#) which changes dynamically when It's source data changes.

For example:

xaml file:

```
<StackPanel>
        <Button Name="scatterButton" Content="click" Click="ScatterButton_Click" />
        <Charting:Chart x:Name="test_chart">
            <Charting:ScatterSeries IndependentValuePath="Name" DependentValuePath="Amount"  />
        </Charting:Chart>
    </StackPanel>
```

c#:

```
    public class SmartPhone
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
    public int Other { get; set; }
}

public sealed partial class MainPage : Page 
{

    List<SmartPhone> lstSource = new List<SmartPhone>
    {
        new SmartPhone() { Name = "IPhone", Amount = 40, Other = 1 },
        new SmartPhone() { Name = "Android", Amount = 30, Other = 1 },
        new SmartPhone() { Name = "UWP", Amount = 25, Other = 2 }
    };

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        LoadChartContent();
    }

    private void LoadChartContent()
    {
        (test_chart.Series[0] as ScatterSeries).ItemsSource = lstSource;
    }

    private void ScatterButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        lstSource[0].Amount = 10;
    }
}
```

The idea is when I click the button "Amount" value change and I want to see it change in the chart.

I tried many packages but this is the only one that really worked for me in UWP. tha NuGet is "WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.DataVisualization".
Please try to focus on "ScatterSeries" since this is the one I need.

Thanks.

Comment: You need so specify what is Charting:Chart. That is not a standard control.

Comment: Sorry didn't even know it's belongs to "WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.DataVisualization". Fixed it in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first you should use `ObservableCollection` instead of `List` to automatically notify when items get added or removed.
To notify about changes you have to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and raise `PropertyChanged` event.

xaml:

```
        <Charting:Chart x:Name="test_chart">
            <Charting:ScatterSeries ItemsSource="{x:Bind LstSource}" IndependentValuePath="Name" DependentValuePath="Amount"  />
        </Charting:Chart>
```

SmartPhone class example:

```
public class SmartPhone : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private int _amount;

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int Amount
        {
            get { return _amount; }
            set
            {
                this._amount = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public int Other { get; set; }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

MainPage class:

```
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {

        public ObservableCollection<SmartPhone> LstSource
        {
            get { return lstSource; }
        }

        private ObservableCollection<SmartPhone> lstSource = new ObservableCollection<SmartPhone>
        {
            new SmartPhone() {Name = "IPhone", Amount = 10, Other = 1},
            new SmartPhone() {Name = "Android", Amount = 30, Other = 1},
            new SmartPhone() {Name = "UWP", Amount = 25, Other = 2}
        };


        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            //LoadChartContent();
        }

        private void ScatterButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            lstSource[0].Amount = 30;
            //lstSource.Add(new SmartPhone{Amount = 10, Name = "asd", Other = 2});

        }
    }
```

I hope it's all you need.